# How to disallow assigning to a temporary object and implicit casting from other type?

Tags: c++, c++11, casting, operators, overloading

I overloaded = operator twice for normal and temporary objects.
Unfortunatelly g++ (Debian 4.7.2-5) 4.7.2 allows too much temporary objects.
For example he shouldn't allow assign to temporary object.
He also allows to assign other type variable to object.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Simple {
    int number;
public:
    int getNumber() const {
        return number;
    }
    Simple(const Simple& that) : number(that.number) {}
    Simple(Simple&& that) : number(move(that.getNumber())) {}
    Simple(int a) {number = a;}
    Simple& operator=(const Simple &base) {
        if (&base != this) {
            this->number = std::move(base.getNumber());
        }
        return *this;
    }
    Simple& operator=(Simple&& base) {
        if (&base != this) {
            this->number = std::move(base.getNumber());
        }
        return *this;
    }
};
Simple reverse(const Simple& base) {
    Simple result(base.getNumber());
    return result;
}
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    Simple one(4);
    Simple two(5);
    one = two.getNumber();//This should be compile error.
    reverse(two) = one;This should be compile error.
    return 0;
}
```

How to change this code to disallow assigning to temporary object 
and implicit casting from other types?

Additional information:
How can I make this instruction implementable:

```
Simple& operator=(Simple const &) && = delete;
```

I tryied to add && = delete at end of my operator declaration but compiler raised compile error. I tried to implement this operator outside class scope but without effects.

Comment: You can give `Simple(int)` an `explicit` specifier to prevent implicit conversions and use an lvalue reference qualifier for your assignment operator to prevent assignment from a temporary instance.

Comment: To disable implicit conversions, make the constructor `explicit`. To disable assignment to temporaries, give `operator=` a `&` ref-qualifier. There is also absolutely no point in moving an `int`.

Comment: No much point in moving an `int`, but if it were not an int, then moving from a `const` object should cause compile-time error in `Simple::operator=(const Simple&)`.

Comment: @Walter There is no "moving from a `const` object"; the result of `getNumber` is a prvalue, passing it through `std::move` has no effect.

Comment: @Casey Technically, it converts the prvalue into an xvalue :P

Comment: @T.C. Which has no observable effects!

Answer (score 4):

The first question is whether you really want to maintain code to inhibit those cases. In general, for a class type, assignment *to* a temporary (rvalue) is allowed, as it is calling any other member function. In C++11 and onwards with rvalue-references you can discriminate rvalues from lvalues during overload resolution and that can be used to block assignment to an rvalue. To block assignment from `int` you can either inhibit all implicit conversions (I'd recommend not having implicit conversions anyway) or blocking the particular assignment operator:

```
class Simple { 
// ...
    // Disallow implicit conversions from int
    explicit Simple(int);

    // Inhibit assignment to rvalues
    Simple& operator=(Simple const &) && = delete;

    // Alternatively, require that it is called on an lvalue
    Simple& operator=(Simple const &s) &;
    Simple& operator=(Simple &&) &;

    // ... or block assigment from 'int'
    Simple& operator=(int) = delete;
};
```

Although to be honest I would just inhibit implicit conversions and leave the rest to the user of the class.

Comment: which compilers do actually implement the trailing `&&` and `&` on member functions correctly?

Comment: @Walter: I would assume that at the very least gcc and clang. The latest SunStudio compiler *claims* (haven't tested) to have full C++11 support, xlC 12.1 claims to support rvalue-references (without any qualifiers, but it does not quite...) VS2013 might (don't know, haven't tested it)

Comment: How can I implement this: Simple& operator=(Simple const &s) &;
    Simple& operator=(Simple &&) &; ???

Comment: @Domandinho: To be clear, I would *not* do this, I don't believe this is something you need to protect your users from. That being said, the implementation is the same that you have in the question.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas I MUST disallow assign to temporary object because this is part of task which my teacher gave to me. Unfortunatelly I can't implement this. No one of solutions from your post were compiled. Maybe I do something wrong but I wasted lot of time trying to solve this without effects...